# How to validate a lang and a country id with Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I would like to validate a lang and a country with Laravel validation. I wonder if it exists something like that:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'branch_id' => 'required|uuid|exists:branches,id',
    'language_id' => 'required|**valid**',
    'translation' => 'required',
    'country_id' => 'required|**valid**'
]);
```

A function like the valid I wrote: `'language_id' => 'required|**valid**'`

How would you do that?

**Edit :**
I do not want to manage countries and languages in tables. I would like to validate or not the country and language with their name. For example 'fr' is a valid language and 'FR' is a valid country. But 'zz' is not a valid language.

But perhaps the good practice would be to have these countries list and languages list in a table (or array) ?

Comment: `'language_id' => 'required|exists:languages,id` ?

Comment: can you be more specific? are you storing the languages / countries on a table?

Comment: Are you talking about writing your own custom validation rules?  If yes, [it is described well in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules).  If not, pls edit your question and clarify, it is not clear right now what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give up on my initial idea (validate the country with a rule). I will simply check with this array I found:

https://gist.github.com/vxnick/380904

Comment: I think this is the best approach.